# Interface method does not run in fragment to receive data

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using an Interface to send a list of objects from an activity to a fragment.
here is my Interface :

```
public interface CurrenciesSync {


void syncCurrencies(List<CurrencyModel> currencies);

}
```

Here is the way I call interface method to set data :

```
    public void getCurrencies(){

    APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<GetCurrenciesModel> call = apiInterface.getCurrencies();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<GetCurrenciesModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetCurrenciesModel> call, Response<GetCurrenciesModel> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                if (response.body().getStatus() == true){
                    currencies = new ArrayList<CurrencyModel>();
                    for (int i = 0 ; i< response.body().getCurrencies().size(); i++){

                        currencies.add(response.body().getCurrencies().get(i));


                    }
                    new FeesFragment();
                    CurrenciesSync currenciesSync = new CurrenciesSync() {
                        @Override
                        public void syncCurrencies(List<CurrencyModel> currencies) {
                            // your code

                        }
                    };
                    currenciesSync.syncCurrencies(currencies);


                }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetCurrenciesModel> call, Throwable t){

        }
    });

}
```

Here is the way I use to get data in fragment :

```
    @Override
public void syncCurrencies(List<CurrencyModel> currencies) {
        List<FeeItemModel> currency = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i= 0 ; i < currencies.size() ; i++){

            currency.add(
                    new FeeItemModel(
                            currencies.get(i).getSomething(),
                            currencies.get(i).getSomething(),
                            currencies.get(i).getSomething(),
                            currencies.get(i).getSomething(),
                            currencies.get(i).getSomething())
            );            }


                    CurrenciesAdaptor currenciesAdaptor = new CurrenciesAdaptor(getContext(),currency);
                    RecyclerView.setAdapter(currenciesAdaptor);
                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    RecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

}
```

but the below method does not run.
Note : the Fragment is being created in another place in myActivity too, and even when I try to make a new instance of fragment to make sure it is being created, nothing changes.

Comment: `new FeesFragment();` – That `Fragment` instance is pointless, as it's not used anywhere; it's simply discarded. `CurrenciesSync currenciesSync = new ...` – That anonymous instance is also pointless, as its implementation has no code, and it doesn't really belong to anything. Basically, that whole section of code doesn't do anything. Your `FeesFragment` class needs to `implements CurrenciesSync`. Then you need to get the instance of the `Fragment` that already exists, and is attached to the `Activity`, and call its `syncCurrencies()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. So how should I initiate CurrenciesSync currenciesSync in my activity to pass data? there is no code in there because I just want to pass an argument and then receive it in fragment. could you show me with code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems when the data is set in the activity class through the interface object, the fragment might not be attached to the activity .And this seems to  not be the correct may to send data from activity to fragment , since this may not every time.

[To use the recommended method to send data from activity to fragment use this link:-](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)

Comment: Thank you. but it's not enough to initiate a new instance of fragment before set data?

Comment: Haven't tried this way but, it as said before the fragment might not have been  attached to the activity when data is set.

Comment: And if u could see interface method defined for sending data from fragment to activity in the link , it captures the interface implementation of the activity in is OnAttach(). A similar thing needs to done here too. Present case is its reverse though, but this might be the missing link.